# Why reference in latex appear before the first page?

Tags: biblatex

Hi all I am using the "Northwestern_2021_PhD_template" and I have put my references but they appear before the first page. If someone has already experienced a similar problem and have a guess, because the code is not possible to share all It is too long and with a lot of images.[image]

Comment: LaTeX reports 75 warnings/errors (there is at least one error) on your document (see the little red icon next to the "Recompile" button). You have to fix *all* errors before you can expect proper output. Start fixing the errors from the top, since errors can have knock-on effects.

Comment: This looks like a leaking auxiliary file, so you may want to clear out the cache between runs https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache. Maybe there is an issue with one of your `\caption`s or headings.

Comment: it is very hard to debug an image. But as the log is showing errors the generated PDF output is not intended to be usable. Show instead the log file with the errors. As your problem with references is on the first page you should be able to easily make a small example that shows the problem. Copy your document to a new project then delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem.

Comment: I manage to solve this by correcting all error, thanks evryone for the time and help @moewe

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is already solved by OP (errors in code not shown)